# Month & year change in Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Datepicker widget in my web application powered by jQuery. Links is http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

It is working fine but i like to store `month & year` in a variable. When next or previous button is clicked variable value should change accordingly. I like to store `date & month` when next or previous button is clicked.

For example, it is showing `July 2013` now by default, so variable value= `07/xx/2013`. xx is date and it may any from 01-30(optional). If i click next button so variable value =`08/xx/2013` or click previous button so variable value =`06/xx/2013`

Please help me, if there any option or method. there is a method var currentDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" ); which show current date. i want current month & year when next / previous button is clicke.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: if you change the month and select a different date it does the same thing you have asked for.

Comment: i like to store date & month when next or previous button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

This is what i want

`$('.datepicker_1').datepicker('option', 'onChangeMonthYear', function(year, month) { var selectedMonth = month });`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#calendar').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
    inline: true,                           
    onChangeMonthYear: function (dateText, inst) {
      console.log(inst + '/' + dateText + 'date');
    },

});
```

Here on change of month and year  of datepicker this onChangeMonthYear will work and we can get dates in year and month